# Need a 64 bit binary for JZMQ, or bulding instructions for a non MSVC environment (cygwin/mingw)?

Tags: cygwin, mingw, jzmq

I'm looking for a binary source for jzmq. Although I've been able to use mingw to build the zmq basic libraries and dlls, I can't use the same technique to compile jzmq myself.

I found this page:
http://www.mail-archive.com/zeromq-dev@lists.zeromq.org/msg06477.html

But it starts with the words: `Run ./autogen.sh on linux (to avoid autotools on mingw32)`

All I really need is a 64 bit binary for now, but can follow instructions that don't requirem me to track down a completely different computer/operating system to get started...

Comment: You can use ./autogen.sh on windows with the MSYS environment that is part of the Mingw project. If you download the latest version of mingw32 with the *mingw-get* utility, it will give you the option to install MSYS and related tools automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me on 64-bit ubuntu 11.04.

1) Configure the environment

```
sudo apt-get install git
sudo apt-get install libtool
sudo apt-get install autoconf
sudo apt-get install automake
```

2) Set JAVA_HOME to location of JDK

Add "JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk" and "export JAVA_HOME" to  /etc/bash.bashrc 
Add ":/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/jre/bin" at the end of the PATH setting in /etc/environment

3) Build the jar

```
cd $HOME
git clone https://github.com/zeromq/jzmq.git
cd jzmq
sudo ./autogen.sh
make
sudo make install
```

4) You should now have zmq.jar in $HOME/jzmq/src

Note: that this build process and the use of zmq.jar relies on having the zmq core already installed, so its probably worthwhile checking that have a whole bunch of libzmq files in /usr/local/lib.